# CS-Cart 4 Site Performance Troubles. Can db caching be the culprit?

Tags: mysql, cs-cart

We've launched our site a little prematurely and have been hit with some nasty performance issues. I am a MS SQL Server professional by trade but have been tasked to tune this MySQL database. As I understand MyISAM databases do not have row level locking and will lock up the entire table if you're editing data. Can someone please confirm or deny my assumptions....

We've spent a lot of money on Google Adwords and have been able to generate some "useless" traffic to the site... but at the same time, we have in house staff loading the site with new products throughout the day. In the evening when no one is inputting anything, I've seen the site load around 2-3 seconds.. but when there are people inputting, the load time drops to 8-9... sometimes 10+ seconds to load.

Also, recently switched our cs-cart caching from "file" to "mysql".. this table, presumably, is also MyISAM.... can this impact performance as well since by nature you'll be writing to this table frequently.

Answer (score 0):

```
    As I understand MyISAM databases do not have row level locking and will lock up the entire table if you're editing data. Can someone please confirm or deny my assumptions....
```

You are right. MyISAM has table level lock only. InnoDB supports row level locks.

Indeed, lock waiting time may be significant if there are many concurrent users access MyISAM tables. But to prove/disprove that you need to collect all queries in a slow log (set long_query_time to 0) and review the log with pt-query-digest. Then you'll see where MySQL spends most of its time. Thus solution may be easier to find.